# Dataflow cannot determine project from environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm running a pretty standard Google Dataflow job and the following error keeps occurring:

`EnvironmentError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment.`

Has this got anything to do with the way I have setup the project?

Full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 609, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 167, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 49, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 50, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 65, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 69, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 159, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 233, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
    self.output(wvalue.with_value((k, wvalue.value)))
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 159, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 392, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 393, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 488, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 496, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 521, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 494, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 283, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
    output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 592, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 392, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 393, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 488, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 496, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 537, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    six.raise_from(new_exn, original_traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 718, in raise_from
    raise value
EnvironmentError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment. [while running 'Save Instances']
```

Comment: How are you passing the project ID environment variable? Can you add a bit more information to your post, like the command you are running, or some code snippet?

Comment: This is happening intermittently on a worker where the project ID is set automatically by the dataflow runner I believe.

Comment: The project ID should be set up somehow (explicitly or environment variables i.e.)., so that could be the problem if you are not setting it up.Actually the error is quite descriptive about that. But can you add some piece of code that you are running, and the command how you are running it i.e. Also, is it the case that the job is actually running and at some point it fails with that error? Or it automatically throws that at the beginning?